# merge audio and video with ffmpeg doesnt work correctly

Tags: ffmpeg

I have ubuntu 20.04 and in past days I did this job(merge video and audio) well in terminal and with ffmpeg:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input2.mp3 -c copy output.mp4`

so fast I have recived output.mp4, but now I tried this one and get output without any sound!

I try another ways to merge this ones(also with ffmpeg) but there are no diffrent...

Comment: Copy and paste **all** of the text that appears after you run ffmpeg. It will shown important info needed for an answer, and so we can give you an answer faster. [Edit] your question to add this info.

Comment: I delete my last post

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(for f in ./input*.mp4; do echo "file '$PWD/$f'"; done)  -c copy output.mp4
```

Note -f concat will select a demuxer. This alters the way -i nput files are read.
So instead video-files 'concat expects a txt-file listing the files to concatenate.
However we somehow omit the creation of that text file and use process substitution to generate and pass that list on the fly to demux.

For more details go here:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer

Answer (score -1):

If you want to merge several video files, you can use these command.

- merge two video files.
  ffmpeg -f concat -i 1.mp4 -1 2.mp4 -codec copy out.mp4
- merge multiple video files.
  ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mpt -vcodec copy -acodec copy out.mp4

Comment: Sorry it won't work like this. 
You may get the error: unknown keyword '?ftypisom' depending on the first file you pass by -i.

RTFM - Well the “concat” Demuxer works different.
It require a txt with FILE <Filename1> ... as input you pass by -i. Here it is nicely explained in detail:
https://www.bannerbear.com/blog/how-to-merge-video-files-using-ffmpeg/